# Upload MSN messenger chat log to gmail

Tags: python, email, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

I am looking for a way to store all my msn messenger chat log (the xml file) to my gmail account.
Just like the gmail chat logs in the "Chats" folder.

1. Is there any program or web service provide this feature?
   I didn't find any program or web service yet. So I guess I may need to write by myself.
2. I find out google provide a gmail api at http://code.google.com/apis/gmail/oauth/.
   It looks like perfect for upload some generated mails to my gmail account. 
   However, It looks like I need to generate extra headers such as "Recevied", "Received-SPF".
   Do all these mail headers required?
3. I would like to download some gmail chat logs as file format reference, but the chat logs looks like cannot download by imap or pop3. Is there a way I can read the raw mail data?

Thank you. Best Regards